# Finding all possible combinations

Tags: javascript, python, permutation

My brain isn't working, and this isn't really Permutation, for example, given the input :

```
ab
```

I want :

```
aa
ab
bb
ba
```

I'm not really sure where to start.

Comment: Good answer using permutations() in here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8306692/1982962

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python, use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> for xs in itertools.product('ab', repeat=2): # 2 == len('ab')
...     print(xs)
...
('a', 'a')
('a', 'b')
('b', 'a')
('b', 'b')
>>> for xs in itertools.product('ab', repeat=2):
...     print(''.join(xs))
...
aa
ab
ba
bb
```

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript,

```
var myString = "ab", result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < myString.length; i += 1) {
    for (var j = 0; j < myString.length; j += 1) {
        result.push(myString[i] + myString[j]);
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

**Output**

```
[ 'aa', 'ab', 'ba', 'bb' ]
```

Comment: I figured it would be something simple, I need more caffeine, thank you!