# Python recursive permutation by integer and returns a set of tuples

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, permutation

First and foremost, I have searched many sites and have taken so much time finding a way to implement this specific requirement. To name a few, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33312532/generate-all-permutations-of-a-string-in-python-without-using-itertools?lq=1) from SO and many others from external sites.

The requirement is fairly simple to understand.

I cannot use `import` and can only use recursive to achieve this task. This function alone must be able to solve the problem by itself. No helper functions allowed.

I have to write a function with this definition:

```
def permutation(n: int) -> set[tuple[int]]:
```

The expected result when calling `permutation(3)` is as follows:

> {(1,2,3),(1,3,2),(2,1,3),(2,3,1),(3,1,2),(3,2,1)}

I feel so frustrated that I cannot come up with any useful attempt to provide here. I tried to think of a solution for this but couldn't come up with anything useful. Therefore, I have no example code to start with.

Comment: I'm guessing you're not allowed to define a helper function within your `permutation()` function?

Comment: @rchome No helper functions allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that if you can get the list of every permutation for n - 1, you can insert `n` in between every point within those permuted results.

```py
def permutation(n):
    if n == 0:
        # base case
        return {()}
    result = set()
    for x in permutation(n - 1):
        for i in range(n):
            # insert n in position i in the permutation of all of the lesser numbers
            result.add(x[:i] + (n,) + x[i:])
    return result
```