# Python - does range() mutate variable values while in recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

While working on understanding string permutations and its implementation in python (regarding to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20955291/1055601)) I stumbled upon something in a `for` loop using `range()` I just don't understand.

Take the following code:

```
def recursion(step=0):
    print "Step I: {}".format(step)
    for i in range(step, 2):
        print "Step II: {}".format(step)
        print "Value i: {}".format(i)

        print "Call recursion"
        print "\n-----------------\n"

        recursion(step + 1)

recursion()
```

That gives the following output:

```
root@host:~# python range_test.py

Step I: 0
Step II: 0
Value i: 0
Call recursion

-----------------

Step I: 1
Step II: 1
Value i: 1
Call recursion

-----------------

Step I: 2
Step II: 0 <---- WHAT THE HECK?
Value i: 1
Call recursion

-----------------

Step I: 1
Step II: 1
Value i: 1
Call recursion

-----------------

Step I: 2
root@host:~#
```

As you can see the variable `step` gets a new value after a certain `for` loop run using `range()` - see the `WHAT THE HECK` mark.

Any ideas to lift the mist?

Comment: `range(2, 2)` is empty. It doesn't enter the `for` loop. So it prints `Step I: 2`, then it returns, the previous function with `range(1, 2)` has then also completed its 1 iteration, so then you're back to where `step` was 0.

Comment: [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conclusion is **incorrect**. `step` value does not change by using `range`.
This can be verified as:

```
def no_recursion(step=0):
    print "Step I: {}".format(step)
    for i in range(step, 2):
        print "Step II: {}".format(step)
        print "Value i: {}".format(i)

no_recursion(step=2)
```

which produces the output:

```
 Step I: 2
```

which is expected since `range(2,2)` returns `[]`.

The illusion that `step` changes its value to 0 comes since the function `recursion` (called with `step=2`) returns after it prints `Step I: 2`, then control is returned to function `recursion` (called with `step=1`) which immediately returns since its `for loop` has terminated, and then control is returned to `recursion` (called with `step=0`) which continues since it has 1 iteration left, and that prints `Step II: 0` to console which is no surprise. This can be simpler to observe if we modify the code a little bit (by adding function entry and exit logging) and observe the output:

```
def recursion(step=0):
    print "recursion called with [step = {}]".format(step) # add entry logging
    print "Step I: {}".format(step)
    for i in range(step, 2):
        print "Step II: {}".format(step)
        print "Value i: {}".format(i)

        print "Call recursion"
        print "\n-----------------\n"

        recursion(step + 1)
    print "--> returned recursion [step = {}]".format(step) # add exit logging 

recursion()
```

the output produced by this code is :

```
recursion called with [step = 0]
Step I: 0
Step II: 0
Value i: 0
Call recursion

-----------------

recursion called with [step = 1]
Step I: 1
Step II: 1
Value i: 1
Call recursion

-----------------

recursion called with [step = 2]
Step I: 2
--> returned recursion [step = 2]
--> returned recursion [step = 1]
Step II: 0
Value i: 1
Call recursion

-----------------

recursion called with [step = 1]
Step I: 1
Step II: 1
Value i: 1
Call recursion

-----------------

recursion called with [step = 2]
Step I: 2
--> returned recursion [step = 2]
--> returned recursion [step = 1]
--> returned recursion [step = 0]
```

where we can clearly see that order in which recursion unfolds and observe that value of `step` is consistent in each step.

Comment: @RalfMarmorglatt glad that helped!