# All permutations of a string in Python

Tags: python, list, permutation

I want to create a program that will take a string, and print out every possible combination of the string.

My idea is to turn the string into a list of letters:

```
scram = input()
scram = list(scram)
```

Then I would use a for loop to iterate through each letter:

```
for letter in scram:
```

The problem is that I would like to move the current letter to the beginning of the string, but I'm not sure how to do that. After that I would try print out every version of the list while the current letter is at the beginning of the list. How could I go about doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306654/finding-all-possible-permutations-of-a-given-string-in-python

Comment: The first answer gives you a solution using python library functions. The 2nd shows you how to do it yourself.