# get all possible strings given multiple strings

Tags: python

I have multiple strings on different lines where I want to get all of the possible permutations without changing the order:

for example:

```
er r er
er er r
```

which would give me:

```
er r er
er er r
er r r
er er er
```

Is there a way to do this is python?  If this is a duplicate please advise but I was not able to find one.

This is different from questions like [Finding all possible permutations of a given string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306654/finding-all-possible-permutations-of-a-given-string-in-python) where only one string is used

Update [Still does not work]

```
import itertools

with open(in_file) as f:
    lis = list(f) 

print (lis)
print([' '.join(x) for x in itertools.product(*map(set, zip(*map(str.split, lis))))])
```

[Error]

```
[['er', 'r', 'er'], ['er', 'er', 'r']]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 37, in <module>
print([' '.join(x) for x in itertools.product(*map(set, zip(*map(str.split, S))))])
TypeError: descriptor 'split' requires a 'str' object but received a 'list'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding all possible permutations of a given string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306654/finding-all-possible-permutations-of-a-given-string-in-python)

Comment: @Kallz but this one only has one string, this I can do... the problem is getting combinations between multiple strings.

Comment: Can you show the data in `in_file`? Note: You are `split()`ing twice, `lis = list(f)` would be sufficient. You could of course just put `f` into the `map()` directly (and move the `print` into the `with` clause). Or you can get rid of the `map()` and just `zip(*lis)`

Comment: @AChampion the in_file is exactly the same as my example

Comment: Then why are you splitting twice?

Comment: @AChamion I can fix that

Comment: @AChampion the output is still the same even without the extra split

Comment: Your error must be incorrect `lis` should be `['er r er', 'er er r']` not the split version you are showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `zip` the splits of these strings and take the cartesion `product`, e.g.:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> s1, s2 = 'er r er', 'er er r'
>>> {' '.join(x) for x in it.product(*zip(s1.split(), s2.split()))}
{'er er er', 'er er r', 'er r er', 'er r r'}
```

You can get duplicates so, constructed as a `set` comprehension.

Updated for an arbitrary number of strings:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> ss = ['er r er', 'er er r', 'ar er r']
>>> {' '.join(x) for x in it.product(*zip(*map(str.split, ss)))}
{'ar er er', 'ar er r', 'ar r er', 'ar r r', 'er er er', 'er er r', 'er r er', 'er r r'}
```

Note: You could also apply the `set` to the arguments to `product` to remove duplicates and it might be quicker depending on the overlaps of the strings, e.g.:

```
>>> [' '.join(x) for x in it.product(*map(set, zip(*map(str.split, ss))))]
['er r r', 'er r er', 'er er r', 'er er er', 'ar r r', 'ar r er', 'ar er r', 'ar er er']
```

To read from a file type object:

```
>>> with open(in_file) as f:
...     lis = list(f)
>>> print([' '.join(x) for x in it.product(*map(set, zip(*map(str.split, lis))))])
['er r r', 'er r er', 'er er r', 'er er er']
```

Or more compactly:

```
>>> with open(in_file) as f:
...     print([' '.join(x) for x in it.product(*map(set, zip(*map(str.split, f))))])
['er r r', 'er r er', 'er er r', 'er er er']
```

Comment: I would like an example that isn't fixed for two strings as I could have more.  I will update my question.

Comment: Please do, as it would require an extraordinary feat of inference to work that out from your question. Note: This is quite easy to update for an arbitrary number of strings.

Comment: I am getting <generator object <genexpr> at , zip is a tuple right?

Comment: `zip()` is a builtin function that takes multiple lists and returns an `iterator` (or `list` py2) of `tuple`s of all the first elements, all the second elements, etc.

Comment: I was thinking something like this: print (' '.join(x for x, _ in itertools.product(S))) I appended my strings to a list hoping that wold help

Comment: and with print({' '.join(x) for x in itertools.product(*zip(*map(str.split, S)))}) I got set(['r', 'er'])

Comment: I would update your question with what you have tried. Showing how `S` is defined, and describe your expected results.

Comment: ok I have put the code and current error up, I got rid of the extra things I was doing.

Comment: See my comment, not sure why you are `split()`ing twice.

Comment: yes, I was trying to make it more obvious but it was unnecessary and I agree with that and produces the same result.  Your updated solution is perfect.  I would also like to than k you for your patience and help on this.  The magic in this solution is the change in format from several strings separated by '\n' to a list of strings (not what I imagined but a working solution) and the use of product from itertools. Thanks again!