# Combinations of a String

Tags: python

The following was a job interview question which I struggled with.
(Unnecessary switching between list and set, tested it and realised it was missing an expected output, too many steps).
If possible, looking for the proper answer or maybe a guide on how I should have tackled the problem. Thank you.

Question: Give a String, find all possible combinations from it (Front and Reverse).
Print all combinations and total count of combinations. Order doesn't matter.

> Example s = 'polo'
>
> Front Answer = 'p', 'po', 'pol', 'polo', 'ol',
> 'olo', 'lo', 'o', 'l'.
> Reverse Answer: 'o', 'ol', 'olo', 'olop',
> 'lop', 'op', 'p', 'l'.

My answer:

```
count = 0
count2 = -1
length = len(s)
my_list = []
for i in s:
    temp = s[count:]
    temp2 = s[:count2]
    my_list.append(i)
    my_list.append(temp)
    my_list.append(temp2)
    count += 1
    count2 -= 1

my_set = set(my_list) 
for f in my_set:
    print(f)
print(len(my_set)) # Answer for front

new_list = []
for f in my_set:
    new_list.append(f[::-1])

print('Reverse Result:')
for f in new_list:
    print(f)
print(len(new_list)) # Answer for reverse
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding all possible permutations of a given string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306654/finding-all-possible-permutations-of-a-given-string-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with two `nested` `for-loops`. One will `loop` through the `start` `indexes` and the `nested` one `loops` through the `end` `indexes` (starting from the `start + 1` going to the length of `s` `+1` to reach the very end).

With these two `indexes` (`start` and `end`), we can use `string` `slicing` to `append` that `combination` to the `list` `forward`. This gives you all the `combinations` as you see below.

To get the reversed ones, you could do a `for-loop` as you have done `reversing` the order of the `forward` ones, but to save the space, in the code below, we just `append` the same `index` but `sliced` from the `reversed` `s` (`olop`).

```
s = "polo"

forward = []
backward = []
for start in range(len(s)):
    for end in range(start+1, len(s)+1):
        forward.append(s[start:end])
        backward.append(s[::-1][start:end])

print(forward)
print(backward)
print(len(forward) + len(backward))
```

which outputs:

```
['p', 'po', 'pol', 'polo', 'o', 'ol', 'olo', 'l', 'lo', 'o']
['o', 'ol', 'olo', 'olop', 'l', 'lo', 'lop', 'o', 'op', 'p']
20
```

If you really wanted to make the code `clean` and `short`, you could do the same thing in a `list-comprehension`. The `logic` remains the same, but we just compress it down to `1` line:

```
s = "polo"

forward = [s[start:end] for start in range(len(s)) for end in range(start+1, len(s)+1)]    
backward = [c[::-1] for c in forward]

print(forward)
print(backward)
print(len(forward) + len(backward))
```

which gives the same output as before.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah... I had `[s[i:e] for i in range(len(s)) for e in range(i + 1, len(s) + 1)]`

Comment: @JonClements I have added the `list-comp` as well now! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   string = "polo"
   x = [string[i:j] for i in range(len(string)) for j in range(len(string),0,-1) if j > i ]
   x.sort()
   print("Forward:",x[::-1])
   print("Reverse:",x[::])
```