# Langford numbers pairing using using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I'm trying to generate Langford numbers with Python. I have already written the following code which works well for getting the fourth Langford number. Here is my code :

```
import itertools

n=0
for l in set(itertools.permutations(["1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4"])):
    t1, t2, t3, t4 = [i for i, j in enumerate(l) if j == "1"], [i for i, j in enumerate(l) if j == "2"], [i for i, j in enumerate(l) if j == "3"], [i for i, j in enumerate(l) if j == "4"]
    if abs(t1[1]-t1[0]) == 2 and abs(t2[1]-t2[0]) == 3 and abs(t3[1]-t3[0]) == 4 and abs(t4[1]-t4[0]) == 5:
        print("".join(l))
        n+=1
    else:
    pass

print(n)
```

I have two questions :

- first, are there techniques to make this code quicker (for the moment it finds the result in 0.1s)
- second, could you give me hints on how I could adapt the code to get any n-th Langford number

I you wonder, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langford_pairing) is the wikipedia page for Langford numbers.

Thank you very much if you take the time to answer me !

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are a few faster ways to make Langford sequences.

Firstly, here's a fairly simple way. Rather than testing all of the permutations containing the pairs of numbers from 1 to n, we generate the permutations of numbers from 1 to n and then try to build Langford sequences from those permutations by placing each pair of numbers into the next available pair of slots. If no pair of slots is available we abandon that permutation and go onto the next one.

Building a sequence is a little slower than simply testing if a full permutation of 2n items is valid, but it means we need to test a *lot* fewer permutations when n is large. Eg, if n=7 there are 7! = 5040 permutations, but if we test the permutations of 7 pairs, that's 14! = 87178291200 permutations!

We can reduce that number though, because it contains a lot of duplicates. For 7 pairs, the number of unique permutations is `14! / (2**7)` = 681080400 since swapping the 2 items in any of the 7 pairs produces a duplicate permutation. Unfortunately, `itertools.permutations` doesn't care about duplicates, but [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43014919/4014959) has code for a permutation generator that doesn't produce duplicate permutations. But still, 681 million permutations is a large number, and it takes a long time to test them. So it's better if we can avoid doing that.

```
import sys
from itertools import permutations

def place(t):
    slen = 2 * len(t)
    seq = [0] * slen
    for u in t:
        # Find next vacant slot
        for i, v in enumerate(seq):
            if v == 0:
                break
        else:
            # No vacant slots
            return
        j = i + u + 1
        if j >= slen or seq[j]:
            return
        seq[i] = seq[j] = u
    return tuple(seq)

def langford(n):
    count = 0
    for t in permutations(range(1, n+1)):
        seq = place(t)
        #if seq and seq < seq[::-1]:
        if seq:
            count += 1
            print(seq, count)
    return count // 2

def main():
    n = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 4
    count = langford(n)
    print(count)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**output for n=7**

```
(1, 4, 1, 5, 6, 7, 4, 2, 3, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7) 1
(1, 4, 1, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 6, 2, 7, 5) 2
(1, 5, 1, 4, 6, 7, 3, 5, 4, 2, 3, 6, 2, 7) 3
(1, 5, 1, 6, 3, 7, 4, 5, 3, 2, 6, 4, 2, 7) 4
(1, 5, 1, 6, 7, 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 6, 4, 7, 3) 5
(1, 5, 1, 7, 3, 4, 6, 5, 3, 2, 4, 7, 2, 6) 6
(1, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 4, 3, 6, 2, 5, 4, 2, 7) 7
(1, 6, 1, 7, 2, 4, 5, 2, 6, 3, 4, 7, 5, 3) 8
(1, 7, 1, 2, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 7, 5, 3, 6, 4) 9
(1, 7, 1, 2, 6, 4, 2, 5, 3, 7, 4, 6, 3, 5) 10
(2, 3, 6, 2, 7, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6, 1, 4, 7, 5) 11
(2, 3, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 1, 4, 1, 7, 6, 5, 4) 12
(2, 4, 7, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 3, 1, 7, 1, 6, 5) 13
(2, 5, 6, 2, 3, 7, 4, 5, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 7) 14
(2, 6, 3, 2, 5, 7, 3, 4, 6, 1, 5, 1, 4, 7) 15
(2, 6, 3, 2, 7, 4, 3, 5, 6, 1, 4, 1, 7, 5) 16
(2, 6, 7, 2, 1, 5, 1, 4, 6, 3, 7, 5, 4, 3) 17
(2, 7, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4, 3, 7, 1, 5, 1, 6) 18
(3, 4, 5, 7, 3, 6, 4, 1, 5, 1, 2, 7, 6, 2) 19
(3, 4, 6, 7, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 6, 1, 7, 1, 5) 20
(3, 5, 7, 2, 3, 6, 2, 5, 4, 1, 7, 1, 6, 4) 21
(3, 5, 7, 4, 3, 6, 2, 5, 4, 2, 7, 1, 6, 1) 22
(3, 6, 7, 1, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 2, 7, 4, 2, 5) 23
(3, 7, 4, 6, 3, 2, 5, 4, 2, 7, 6, 1, 5, 1) 24
(4, 1, 6, 1, 7, 4, 3, 5, 2, 6, 3, 2, 7, 5) 25
(4, 1, 7, 1, 6, 4, 2, 5, 3, 2, 7, 6, 3, 5) 26
(4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 4, 1, 5, 3, 6, 2, 7, 3, 2) 27
(4, 6, 1, 7, 1, 4, 3, 5, 6, 2, 3, 7, 2, 5) 28
(4, 6, 1, 7, 1, 4, 5, 2, 6, 3, 2, 7, 5, 3) 29
(4, 6, 3, 5, 7, 4, 3, 2, 6, 5, 2, 1, 7, 1) 30
(5, 1, 7, 1, 6, 2, 5, 4, 2, 3, 7, 6, 4, 3) 31
(5, 2, 4, 6, 2, 7, 5, 4, 3, 1, 6, 1, 3, 7) 32
(5, 2, 4, 7, 2, 6, 5, 4, 1, 3, 1, 7, 6, 3) 33
(5, 2, 6, 4, 2, 7, 5, 3, 4, 6, 1, 3, 1, 7) 34
(5, 2, 7, 3, 2, 6, 5, 3, 4, 1, 7, 1, 6, 4) 35
(5, 3, 6, 4, 7, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 2, 1, 7, 1) 36
(5, 3, 6, 7, 2, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 7, 1, 4) 37
(5, 6, 1, 7, 1, 3, 5, 4, 6, 3, 2, 7, 4, 2) 38
(5, 7, 1, 4, 1, 6, 5, 3, 4, 7, 2, 3, 6, 2) 39
(5, 7, 2, 3, 6, 2, 5, 3, 4, 7, 1, 6, 1, 4) 40
(5, 7, 2, 6, 3, 2, 5, 4, 3, 7, 6, 1, 4, 1) 41
(5, 7, 4, 1, 6, 1, 5, 4, 3, 7, 2, 6, 3, 2) 42
(6, 1, 5, 1, 7, 3, 4, 6, 5, 3, 2, 4, 7, 2) 43
(6, 2, 7, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4, 3, 7, 1, 5, 1) 44
(7, 1, 3, 1, 6, 4, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 2, 5) 45
(7, 1, 4, 1, 6, 3, 5, 4, 7, 3, 2, 6, 5, 2) 46
(7, 2, 4, 5, 2, 6, 3, 4, 7, 5, 3, 1, 6, 1) 47
(7, 2, 4, 6, 2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 3, 6, 1, 5, 1) 48
(7, 2, 6, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 7, 6, 4, 1, 5, 1) 49
(7, 3, 1, 6, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 2, 6, 4, 2, 5) 50
(7, 3, 6, 2, 5, 3, 2, 4, 7, 6, 5, 1, 4, 1) 51
(7, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6, 4, 3, 7, 5, 2, 3, 6, 2) 52
26
```

That takes about 0.2 seconds on my old 2GHz machine.

Conventionally, 2 Langford sequences are considered to be the same if one is a reversal of the other. One way to deal with that is to compare a sequence with its reversed version, and only print it if its less than the reversed version. You can change the above code to do that by commenting out

```
if seq:
```

in the `langford` function and un-commenting the following line:

```
#if seq and seq < seq[::-1]:
```

---

The above code is an improvement, but we can do better. My next solution uses a technique known as recursive [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking). This technique can be elegantly implemented in Python through the use of a recursive generator function.

We start with a sequence of zeros. Starting with the highest number, we try to place a pair of numbers into each legal pair of slots, and if we're successful we recurse to place the next pair of numbers, if there are no numbers left to place we've found a solution and we can yield it.

```
import sys

def langford(n, seq):
    ''' Generate Langford sequences by recursive backtracking '''
    # The next n
    n1 = n - 1
    # Test each valid pair of positions for this n
    for i in range(0, len(seq) - n - 1):
        j = i + n + 1
        if not (seq[i] or seq[j]):
            # Insert this n into the sequence
            seq[i] = seq[j] = n
            if n1:
                # Recurse to add the next n
                yield from langford(n1, seq)
            else:
                # Nothing left to insert
                yield seq
            # Remove this n from the sequence in preparation
            # for trying the next position
            seq[i] = seq[j] = 0

def main():
    n = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 4
    for i, t in enumerate(langford(n, [0] * 2 * n), 1):
        print(t, i)
        if i % 1000 == 0:
            print(' ', i, end='\r', flush=True)
    print('\n', i // 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The `if i % 1000 == 0:` stuff lets you see the progress when `n` is large. This is handy if you comment-out the `print(t, i)` line.

This code can generate the 35584 = 2*17792 sequences for n=11 in under 25 seconds on my machine.

---

If you want to collect the sequences yielded by `langford` into a list, rather than just printing them, you can do it like this:

```
n = 7
results = list(langford(n, [0] * 2 * n))
```

However, if you want to do that you **must** make a slight change to the `langford` function. Where it says

```
yield seq
```

change it to

```
yield seq[:]
```

so that it yields a copy of `seq` rather than the original `seq` list.

If you just want to get the count of sequences (not counting reversals), you can do this:

```
n = 7
count = sum(1 for _ in langford(n, [0] * 2 * n)) // 2
print(count)
```

That will work ok with `yield seq`.

---

The above code will be slow for larger values of `n`. There are faster techniques for calculating the number of Langford sequences, using fairly advanced mathematics, but there's no known simple formula. The OEIS has a list of Langford sequences numbers at [A014552](https://oeis.org/A014552).

Answer (score -1):

You are complicating things: All that is needed is to generate all permutations, and eliminate those that are not Langford sequences.

1- do not use `set(itertools...)`, itertools already returns unique elements.
2- for each permutation, you must check is it is a Langfort sequence.
3- if not, break and check the next one
4- if it is, check that its inverse has not yet been collated, and save it in a set of unique elements
5- return the resulting unique langfort sequences

This code is fast for n=4, and can find sequences for an arbitrary `n`; however, the time complexity is massively exponential; past `n=6`, it will require quite a bit of time to finish.

```
import itertools

def langfort(n):
    seq = [_ for _ in range(1, n+1)] * 2
    lang = set()
    for s in itertools.permutations(seq):
        for elt in seq:
            first = s.index(elt)
            if s[first+1:].index(elt) == elt:
                continue
            else:
                break
        else:
            if s[::-1] not in lang:
                lang.add(s)
    return lang

langfort(4)
```

#### output:

```
{(4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2)}
```

#### Performance:

on a 2011 mac book air:

```
%timeit langfort(4)
10 loops, best of 3: 53.4 ms per loop
```

#### more output:

```
langfort(5)
set()          # there are no langfort(5) sequences
```

---

```
langfort(6)
set()          # there are no langfort(6) sequences
```

Comment: That's not going to be very fast for larger n. :) You may enjoy my answer.