# Permutations Python

Tags: python, permutation

How do I take, for example, this tuple ("A", "E", "L") and generate all possible words without repeating the letters? The result would be 3 words with only one letter, 6 words with two letters and 6 words with 3 letters.

I tried this:

```
def gererate(tuplo_letras):
    return [i for i in itertools.permutations(tuplo_letras)]

def final(arg):
    return generate(list(map(''.join, itertools.permutations(arg))))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306654/finding-all-possible-permutations-of-a-given-string-in-python

Comment: Pls post your own attempt!

Comment: def gererate(tuplo_letras):
 return [i for i in itertools.permutations(tuplo_letras)]

def final(arg):
 return generate(list(map(''.join, itertools.permutations(arg))))

Comment: In the question, not the comments ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) and iterate over all the lengthes of the permutations you want to cover. Note that `permutations` takes two arguments, the iterable and the desired length of the permutations you want:

```
from itertools import permutations, chain

tpl = ("A", "E", "L")
[''.join(p) for p in chain(*(permutations(tpl, l+1) for l in range(len(tpl))))]
# ['A', 'E', 'L', 'AE', 'AL', 'EA', 'EL', 'LA', 'LE', 'AEL', 'ALE', 'EAL', 'ELA', 'LAE', 'LEA']
```

If you need them grouped you can nest the comprehensions accordingly:

```
[[''.join(p) for p in (permutations(tpl, l+1))] for l in range(len(tpl))]
# [['A', 'E', 'L'], ['AE', 'AL', 'EA', 'EL', 'LA', 'LE'], ['AEL', 'ALE', 'EAL', 'ELA', 'LAE', 'LEA']]
```

Comment: And how do I create new lists based on the length of the words? I  mean, put in one lists all the words with one letter, in another list the words with two words and so on?

Comment: Updated it with a nested list grouped by length variant.

Comment: And if I had to select words based on another condition how would I do that?

Comment: One question at a time ... but you can add an if clause to the comprehensions: `[x for y in lst if condition(x)]`

Comment: Because I have another function that decides if the words are valid or not and I want to choose from the list above the the which are valid.