# Combinations without duplicates of all elements in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

To clarify the picture, if i have a string:

```
'pac'
```

I would want to get the list of every permutation of it, in this example:

```
['p', 'a', 'c', 'pa', 'pc', 'pac']
```

Just like i would type any of it in some search engine like the one on Ebay and it would pop up "pac" as a suggestion.

Code bellow is what i achieved thus far, but it's obviously not working as it should. 'Names' is just a list with multiple names, for instance: ['pac', 'greg', 'witch']

```
    letters = {}
    for name in names:
        temp = []
        letter = []
        temp2 = []

        for let in name:
            let = let.lower()
            temp.append(let)
            letter.append(let)

        for i in range(0, len(name)):
            for j in range(1, len(name) - i):
                print(i, j, end='  ')

                to_add = letter[i] + temp[j]
                print(to_add, temp2)

                temp2.append(to_add)
                letter.append(to_add)
            temp = temp2
            temp2 = []

        letters[name] = letter
    return letters
```

If there is built-in function feel free to share it with me, but that's not the core of the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306654/finding-all-possible-permutations-of-a-given-string-in-python

Comment: Just use permutations and list comprehension  - your code contains a lot of extra work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding all possible permutations of a given string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306654/finding-all-possible-permutations-of-a-given-string-in-python)

Comment: What happened to 'ac'? And it looks like you want combinations, not permutations. The set of all combinations is called the power set, see the itertools docs for a recipe.

Answer (score 6):

User standard library `itertools`:

```
In [48]: T = 'pac'

In [49]: list(itertools.chain(*[itertools.combinations(T, i+1) for i in range(len(T))]))
Out[49]: [('p',), ('a',), ('c',), ('p', 'a'), ('p', 'c'), ('a', 'c'), ('p', 'a', 'c')]
```

It break down into:

1, `itertools.combinations(['p', 'a', 'c'], i)` to generate all the subsample of 'pac' with sample size `i`

2, repeat `i` for `i=1, 2, 3`, and put the resultant three `itertools.combination` objects in a list

3, unpack the list from #2, and use the those as the parameter to generate an `itertools.chain` object (as the name implies, it will chain its args together). See more on arguments [unpack](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/)

In a lot of real world use cases, especially when the total number of the elements are large, you don't actual want to make a list out of the `itertools.chain` object. The point of using `itertools` are often to achieve memory efficiency by avoiding having to putting all its members in memory.

(if you don't want `tuple`s just add a `''.join` to get them back to strings)

Comment: I understand what is going on here, but I think you should *generally* explain what is going on with the line: `list(itertools.chain(*[itertools.combinations(list(T), i+1) for i in range(len(T))]))` so that way OP doesnt just copy+paste, but learns HOW it works.

Comment: You really don't need `list(T)` and your claim for memory efficiency is lost (for this example - but generally true) because you expand the arguments to `itertools.chain()`. You could maintain memory efficiency with `itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.combination(T, i+1) for i in range(len(T)))` - a generator expression vs an expanded list comprehension.