# Why does [""] not behave as expected in recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

I am going through popular interview questions, and came up with the following solution to "Compute all permutations of a string."

```
def perm(s):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return ['']
    else:
        l = []
        prev = perm(s[1:])
        for old_str in prev:
            for i in range(len(old_str)):
                new_str = old_str[0:i] + s[0] + old_str[i:]
                l.append(new_str)
        return l
```

However, this solution returns `[]` on all input. If I make the string in the base case any string other than the empty string, the computation runs as expected. For example, with 'hi' in the base case, `perm('abc')` returns

`['abchi', 'bachi', 'bcahi', 'bchai', 'acbhi', 'cabhi', 'cbahi', 'cbhai', 'achbi', 'cahbi', 'chabi', 'chbai', 'abhci', 'bahci', 'bhaci', 'bhcai', 'ahbci', 'habci', 'hbaci', 'hbcai', 'ahcbi', 'hacbi', 'hcabi', 'hcbai']`

As far as I can tell the algorithm for this code is correct. I am unsure of why the empty string isn't behaving as I anticipate, while other strings do. I have referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306654/finding-all-possible-permutations-of-a-given-string-in-python) thread for better solutions, but I am still puzzled by why this one doesn't work.

Comment: The algorithm is *not* correct.

Comment: See [For loop uses a recursive call's output as parameter](//stackoverflow.com/q/51809957) for a question asked earlier today that produces correct permutations. See if you can spot the difference between the implementations. Ignore the fact that the other works with tuples rather than strings.

Comment: Notice how `perm('')` and `perm('a')` differ. The latter should return `['a']`, but doesn't. Try to work through the logic to see why it returns an empty list in that case. Compare this with the other implementation to see if you can spot why that version does work.

Comment: My algorithm was to compute all permutations of the previous string, then insert the current character of the string to all indices of the permutations of the smaller string. From what I can tell, this is the method that is being used in Cracking the Coding Interview, however the code is Java. Any hints on what I'm missing?

Comment: How many times will `range(len(old_str))` iterate for the case where `s` is length 1, and thus `prev` is a list with a string of length 0?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add a special case for len(s)==1.

As written, the recursion will go down to the base case with an empty string, and then prev will be []. The for loop that follows this will never run, because prev is empty, so the final result will be empty too.