# Issue generating a list of permutations of a string

Tags: python

I want to generate a list of all permutations of a string using a backtracking algorithm.

I modified some code from a previous post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20955291/12021192

```py
def permutations(string, step = 0):

    permTrack = []

    if step == len(string):
        permTrack.append(''.join(string))

    for i in range(step, len(string)):
        string_copy = list(string)
        string_copy[step], string_copy[i] = string_copy[i], string_copy[step]
        permutations(string_copy, step + 1)

    return permTrack

permTrack = permutations('ABC')
```

I expected `permTrack = ['ABC', 'ACB', 'BAC', 'BCA', 'CAB', 'CBA]`, but the actual output is `permTrack = [ ]`.

The idea is to is to append to a list permTrack at the base case, when step == len(string). This works for instance in the original code to print the permutations.

Can someone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't do anything with what is returned by `permutations` when it is called recursively.

If you add what gets returned to `permTrack`, you should get what you want.

Comment: I see my mistake, also a previous answer that was deleted was helpful.  I modified my code by adding a new parameter in the function:  def permutations(string, step = 0, permTrack = [ ]).  Then, deleting permTrack = [ ] in the function body.  This produces the desired output. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need a new parameter; you just need to take what gets returned by `permutations` in the recursive call and add its elements to what is in `permTrack`.