# Find the length of the palindrome that can be made from a string in Python

Tags: python, string, palindrome

I try to make program to find the length of the palindrome that can be made from a string in Python, but I got wrong result.

This is  my program but I still get wrong results, maybe anyone can help me to fixed this.

```
from typing import Counter
def checkpalindrom(s):
    mid = len(s)/2
    end = len(s)-1
    i = 0
    while  i<= mid:
        if s[i]!= s[end-i]:
            return False
    return True
def deletepalindrom(s):
    if deletepalindrom(s)==True:
        return 0
    min = 100
    x = 0
    while x < len(s):
        temp = s
        temp.remove(1)
        Counter = deletepalindrom(temp)+1
        if Counter<=min:
            min = Counter
n = int(input())
for y in range(n):
    s = input()
    print(len(s)- deletpalindrom(s))
```

I got a redline in line `print(len(s)- deletpalindrom(s))` to show the length and also in line `temp.remove(1)` got `'str' object has no attribute 'remove'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following to achieve what you want:

```
from itertools import permutations


def get_len_palindrome(string):
    all_permutations = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(string)]
    lst_palindrome_lengths = []

    for permutation in all_permutations:
        for i in range(len(permutation)+1):
            if permutation[:i] == permutation[:i][::-1]:
                lst_palindrome_lengths.append(i)

    lst_palindrome_lengths.sort(reverse=True)
    return lst_palindrome_lengths[0]
            
n = int(input())
for y in range(n):
    s = input()
    print(get_len_palindrome(s))
```

The function `get_len_palindrome(string)` first [utilises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306654/finding-all-possible-permutations-of-a-given-string-in-python) the `permutations` method of the `itertools` module to obtain all permutations of a given `string`, then, drawing from a pythonic way to check for palindromes suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331290/how-to-check-for-palindrome-using-python-logic), uses the permutations obtained this way to determine the lengths of palindromes constructed from this `string` and returns the maximum length.

Answer (score 0):

It is helpful to make the following observations:

- In a palindrome `p`, at most one letter appears an odd number of times.
- The maximum length of a palindrome formed using letters in a string `w` is fully determined by the letter "frequencies" of the string `w`. For example, the answer for `aab` is the same as the answer for `bba`.

With the observations in mind, here is one solution using `collections.Counter`.

---

```
from collections import Counter

xs = ['wewewe', 'pelatnas', 'kedua', 'di', 'jogja']
ys = [5, 3, 1, 1, 3]

def pal_len(s):
  result = 0
  # letter frequencies
  ctr = Counter(s)
  # False only if each letter appears an even number of times
  have_spare = False
  for k, v in ctr.items():
    # letter k appears v times
    # if v is even, we can add v characters to the palindrome
    # if v is odd, we can add v - v%2 characters to the palindrome
    remainder = v % 2
    result += v - remainder
    if remainder:
      have_spare = True
  # at this point, have_spare == True whenever
  # there is a character that appears an odd number of times in s
  # we can insert such a character in the middle of the palindrome
  return result + have_spare
  
assert all(pal_len(x) == y for x, y in zip(xs, ys))
```