# Generate all permutations from 1 to n in python with recursion

Tags: python, recursion

Given a natural number n. We try to generate all permutations from 1 to n in Python without any prebuild method. I used recursion as follows to achieve our desired goal in python

```
# Generate all permutations in Python with recursion


n = int(input('Enter a number: '))

permutationLst = []
validlst = [0] * (n + 1)


def generate():
    if len(permutationLst) >= n:
        print(permutationLst)
        return None

    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if validlst[i]:
            continue

        validlst[i] = 1
        permutationLst.insert(i, i)
        generate()
        permutationLst.pop()
        validlst[i] = 0


generate()
```

But the output of above code is for n=3 is:

```
Enter a number: 3
[1, 2, 3]

[1, 3, 2]

[2, 1, 3]

[2, 1, 3]

[3, 1, 2]

[3, 1, 2]
```

How can I resolve this problem that some permutations are not generated and duplicates are generated? Note that I'm a beginner in Python.

I try to analyze the recursion tree of my code but I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: Did you googled that question ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/104420 //  https://stackoverflow.com/q/8306654

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with your current implementation is that you are not properly handling the state of the validlst list and the permutationLst list when you backtrack after generating a permutation.

To fix this issue, you need to modify your code as follows:

```
n = int(input('Enter a number: '))
permutationLst = []
validlst = [0] * (n + 1)


def generate():
    if len(permutationLst) == n:
        print(permutationLst)
        return None

    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if validlst[i]:
            continue

        validlst[i] = 1
        permutationLst.append(i)
        generate()
        permutationLst.pop()
        validlst[i] = 0


generate()
```

[image: OUTPUT of the Code]

The changes are:

- In the if condition, you should check for the length of
  permutationLst to be equal to n, not greater than or equal to n.
- Use the append() method instead of insert() to add an element to
  permutationLst.
- In the backtracking step, you should remove the last
  element from permutationLst using the pop() method.
- You should reset the value of validlst[i] to 0 after backtracking.

With these modifications, your code should generate all permutations of 1 to n without duplicates.